Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<
i am having an error when i invoke the method notDoneRepo.findAllNDPEntities() after having created lists of the RecordEntity, i get the conversion error,note that NotDoneRecordEntity extends the RecordEntity, if i call the line  List<NotDoneRecordEntity>  allNDPs =notDoneRepo.findAllNDPEntities(); before creating the lists of RecordEntity, i have no errors and i can create more lists of type NotDoneRecordEntity after, but if i dont and proceed to create these list first in the code, i get the convertion error and the no converter found error
  private void testMonth() {
       
        List<RecordEntity> pActionM = recordService.getAllMonthActionRecords(fileMonth);
        List<RecordEntity> othersAsStudy = new ArrayList<>();
        List<RecordEntity> inSearchRecords = new ArrayList<>();
// line of error
        List<NotDoneRecordEntity>  allNDPs =notDoneRepo.findAllNDPEntities();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "not_done_records")
@DiscriminatorValue("not_done_records")
@Data
public class NotDoneRecordEntity extends RecordEntity {
}

the NotDoneRepository where the method is defined
@Repository
public interface NotDoneRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<NotDoneRecordEntity,String> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM NotDoneRecordEntity p WHERE TYPE(p) = NotDoneRecordEntity")
    List<NotDoneRecordEntity> findAllNDPEntities();
}

